# Kill process by ppid in python?

Tags: python, kill, pid

In python using: `os.kill()` will kill a process by pid using a specified signal,
How would one go about killing all processes with the same **ppid**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your parent process ID is 7773.

I haven't done this myself, but you might try:

```
import subprocess

ppid = '7773'
subprocess.call(['pkill', '-STOP', '-P', ppid])
```

To get the ppid of the current process:

```
import os
ppid = os.getppid()
```

Perhaps there is a solution that is strictly python. If so, I don't know what it is.

EDIT: psutil

If you want a true python solution, the [psutil package](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Processes) might have what you're looking for.